# <ComponentName> was created without expected prop 'segment'

Tags: svelte

When you create empty [Svelte](https://svelte.dev) component (eg. `ComponentName.svelte`) like this:

```
<script>
    export let segment;
</script>

<style>
</style>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
</svelte:head>

<p>lorem ipsum...</p>
```

you will have error:

```
<ComponentName> was created without expected prop 'segment'
```

Answer (score 39):

This is to help you debug — you've defined a `segment` prop, but the consumer of the component isn't giving it a value, which is likely to be the cause of bugs. Either the consumer should provide a value — `<ComponentName segment="foo"/>` — or you should a) remove the prop, or b) give it a default value (which can be `undefined`):

```js
export let segment = undefined;
```

Any of those three actions will prevent the warning from appearing.

Comment: unfortunately setting a prop to undefined or an empty string still shows the warning, which is quite annoying when you actually need the prop but also want to leave it undefined initially

Comment: Thanks Rich! undefined did the trick for me

Comment: It works, both `undefined` and `null` will eliminate the warning. Though I'm wondering .. isn't the default value `undefined` ?

Comment: This only worked for me if I set it to `null`; an explicit `undefined` left the same warning.

Answer (score -2):

Hacky solution to suppress all of these, use at your own risk:

**+layout.js**

```
if (__SVELTEKIT_DEV__) {
    const warn = console.warn;
    console.warn = (...args) => {
        if (
            args.length === 1 &&
            /was created (with unknown|without expected) prop/.test(args[0])
        ) {
            return;
        }
        warn(...args);
    };
}
```